# Function keys are not working on Samsung NP300

Tags: shortcut-keys, samsung

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 from last week. This model of Samsung has <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, when used with <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F8</kbd>, it can control brightness, volume and some other stuff.

Everything was working perfectly. Few minutes ago, I locked computer by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and started cleaning up the keyboard. When I logged back in, the <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F8</kbd> keys are working for controlling laptop features and they won't work for what they actually are.. i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> doesn't work anymore. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to `tty1` doesn't work.

It seems like, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is recorded as 'pressed' in the system. How do I resolve this?

Comment: This will work without doubt-http://www.voria.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1091....i myself use samsung and this worked :)

Answer (score 2):

While cleaning the keyboard, you would have pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd> Lock button which is next to the <kbd>F12</kbd> button so the function keys are locked, press it again; it will unlock the function keys so that you can use the function key properly.